# C# regular expression ignores extra data at ends

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regex in C# that has the following characteristics.

1. The string starts with zero or more numbers
2. Followed by the letters "ABC"
3. Followed by the end of the string

I've tried

```
\d?ABC
```

but still matches things like `ZABC`, `ABCD`, `2ZABC`.

any pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to represent the start and end of the string:

```
^\d?ABC$
```

Also, `?` means 0 or 1. 0 or more is `*`:

```
^\d*ABC$
```

Also note that depending on the active `Culture` in .NET `\d` can be interpreted as "any Unicode digit character". If you really only want the ASCII digits use a character class:

```
^[0-9]*ABC$
```

The [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) on that website is a great resource to learn regular expressions.